# Best spacetime metric for a cylinder

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, models

I am studying a rotating cylinder model in general relativity. The interior metric is given, but I am trying to express the exterior metric. It has to be practical and describe spacetime around a rotating cylinder. So far I have considered the Kerr metric, of course, the Janice-Newman-Winicour metric, and the Tomimatsu-Sato metric. For the Kerr metric, I am struggling to express it in cylindrical coordinates. Doing so will make it easier to match it to the interior metric. Any suggestions or inputs would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain why the Kerr metric, which in a naive sense is the metric of a rotating point mass (which doesn’t extend to infinity), would have anything to do with a rotating *cylinder* (which does extend to infinity)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well the Kerr metric is not necessarily limited to that interpretation right? It is more importantly a vacuum solution of the EFEs. The model of the cylinder need not have infinite length either. In short, I feel it can still be used to describe the geometry in the matter free space of a rotating object. Also my model is asymptotically flat. So it would make sense...